# How to fix Timeout_expired crashes in Windows Phone 81 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-dev-center

I am getting a lot of crashes in failure report on my Dev Center account like:

```
XXXXXXX!{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_TargetStateChanged,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_NavigatingTo,_tar

MISSING_DUMP_EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_XXXXXXX!{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_TargetStateChanged,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_NavigatingTo,_tar

EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_XXXXXXX!{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_TargetStateChanged,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_Showing,_targetSt

MISSING_DUMP_EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_XXXXXXX!{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_SystemKeyPressed,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState
```

I'm not able to fix them in my app because in Failure Log there is no stacktrace for them and this kind of crashes are not catched by Application Insights.

Comment: Windows Phone automatically kills applications that are unresponsive for a few seconds. Are you doing lengthy calculations in the UI thread? Like downloading something from the network?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am downloading data from network and I'm doing this in navigationhelper.loadstate method. Every example shows that this is a proper aproach to load data.

Comment: Just in case this is happening with you in case of Javascript UWP App. This link may give you some insight - https://www.groovypost.com/tips/wwahost-exe-windows-process-safe-running-or-virus/

Answer (score 3):

The EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444 error is a big mystery to everyone.

a lot of developers have them in the dashboard and they are not reproducable, and and they suddenly came when the Dashboard got a mayor update.

The error occurs in all kind of apps; with c++ runtime components and without, in background thread and in apps that do not use background threads at all....

Finally; there is not way to get the stacktrace and there is no way to catch it yourself because UnhandledException event doesn't get hit.

Meanwhile I'm ignoring the error, up until MSFT gives a proper explanation in the dashboard what this error means.

PS: if someone magically knows to solve/get more info out of this exceptions; I would love to hear about it.

Comment: I am in the same situation and what you said is totally right. This seems to be the real situation. Just in case, if you have come across any solution to this, Please let me know! Thanks.